# Laravel 2-factor authentication set up

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a 2-factor authentication each time a user log in to the account. For this I want an OTP functionality to be added which sends the OTP to user' registered email Id and then redirect to the dashboard.
My route file:

```
'''
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Backpack\Base Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This file is where you may define all of the routes that are
| handled by the Backpack\Base package.
|
*/

Route::group(
[
    'namespace'  => 'Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers',
    'middleware' => config('backpack.base.web_middleware', 'web'),
    'prefix'     => config('backpack.base.route_prefix'),
],
function () {
    // if not otherwise configured, setup the auth routes
    if (config('backpack.base.setup_auth_routes')) {
        // Authentication Routes...
        Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('backpack.auth.login');
        Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
        //Route for otp form -by harshita aggarwal (26-June-2021)
        Route::get('otp', 'Auth\LoginController@otpForm')->name('admin.otp');
        Route::post('otp','Auth\LoginController@otpLogin')->name('backpack.auth.login.otp');
        
        Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('backpack.auth.logout');
        Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');

        // Registration Routes...
        Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('backpack.auth.register');
        Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

        // if not otherwise configured, setup the password recovery routes
        if (config('backpack.base.setup_password_recovery_routes', true)) {
            Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('backpack.auth.password.reset');
            Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
            Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('backpack.auth.password.reset.token');
            Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('backpack.auth.password.email');
        }
    }

    // if not otherwise configured, setup the dashboard routes
    if (config('backpack.base.setup_dashboard_routes')) {
        Route::get('dashboard', 'AdminController@dashboard')->name('backpack.dashboard');
        Route::get('/', 'AdminController@redirect')->name('backpack');
    }

    // if not otherwise configured, setup the "my account" routes
    if (config('backpack.base.setup_my_account_routes')) {
        Route::get('edit-account-info', 'MyAccountController@getAccountInfoForm')->name('backpack.account.info');
        Route::post('edit-account-info', 'MyAccountController@postAccountInfoForm')->name('backpack.account.info.store');
        Route::post('change-password', 'MyAccountController@postChangePasswordForm')->name('backpack.account.password');
    }
});'''
```

My LoginController:

```
'''
<?php

namespace Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use App\Mail\otpLogin;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    protected $data = []; // the information we send to the view

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */
    use AuthenticatesUsers {
        logout as defaultLogout;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $guard = backpack_guard_name();

        $this->middleware("guest:$guard", ['except' => 'logout']);

        // ----------------------------------
        // Use the admin prefix in all routes
        // ----------------------------------

        // If not logged in redirect here.
        $this->loginPath = property_exists($this, 'loginPath') ? $this->loginPath
            : backpack_url('login');

        // Redirect here after successful login.
        $this->redirectTo = property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo
            : backpack_url('dashboard');

        // Redirect here after logout.
        $this->redirectAfterLogout = property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout
            : backpack_url('login');
    }

    /**
     * Return custom username for authentication.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function username()
    {
        return backpack_authentication_column();
    }

    /**
     * The user has logged out of the application.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function loggedOut(Request $request)
    {
        return redirect($this->redirectAfterLogout);
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during logout.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard()
    {
        return backpack_auth();
    }
    
    /**
     * Function attempLogin added by Harsh Agarwal on 10-Apr-2021 to add user status check in login attempt
     * This login is a default function to Auth class which is being overridden from here
     */
    protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $this->credentials($request);
        $credentials['status'] = 1; //Adding User Status column in login attempt to verify that user is enabled
        
        return $this->guard()->attempt(
            $credentials, $request->filled('remember')
        );
    }
    /*
     * @purpose: to handle login redirections and send otp to user via mail
     * @author: Harshita Aggarwal
     * @Date: 26-June-2021
     */
    public function login(Request $request){
        $this->validateLogin($request);
        //check whether the user entered an email id or not
        if(!empty($request->email)){
            $user = User::where('email',$request->email)->pluck('status')->toArray();
            if($user !=null){//if user is registered
                //if status of user is active or 1
                if($user[0]==1){
                    $otp = rand(1000, 9999);
                    
                    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

                    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
                        //Mail::to($request->email)->send(new otpLogin($otp));
                        //User::where('email',$request->email)->update(['otp'=>$otp]);
                        // Authentication passed...
                        //return redirect(backpack_url('otp'))->withInput();
                        return redirect()->route('admin.otp');
                    }else{
                        \Alert::error(trans('base.invalid_credentials'))->flash();
                        //Redirect to the page where request has been raised
                        return redirect()->back();
                    }
                    
                }
                else{
                    \Alert::error(trans('base.user_status_deactive'))->flash();
                    //Redirect to the page where request has been raised
                    return redirect()->back();
                }
            }
            else{
                \Alert::error(trans('base.user_not_registered'))->flash();
                //Redirect to the page where request has been raised
                return redirect()->back();
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    /*
     * @purpose: to redirect to otp form for login verification
     * @author: Harshita Aggarwal
     * @Date:26-June-2021
     */
    public function otpForm(Request $request){
        $val = $request->old('email');
        $val1 = $request->old('password');
        return view(backpack_view('auth.otp'),['val'=>$val,'val1'=>$val1]);
    }
    /*
     * 
     */
    public function otpLogin(Request $request){
        $otp = User::where('email',$request->email)->pluck('otp')->toArray();
        if($request->otp == $otp[0]){
            User::where('email',$request->email)->update(['otp'=>0]);
//            var_dump('done');die;
            //return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
            $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

            if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
                // Authentication passed...
                return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
            }
            }
        else{
            dd('no');
        }
    }
}
'''
```

The redirection to the otp blade file fails. As it shows 404 status code. What could be a possible solution?

Comment: Did you find the fix for this? I am also facing the same issue. Can anyone help?